# No audio after upgrading kernel to 5.15.0-60

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa

After upgrading to new kernel all audio in/out was lost.  Reverting back to previous kernel restores audio.   While booted into the new kernel, I found that if I run "alsamixer" on the command line, I get:

alpha@Gaia2:~$ alsamixer
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

So the new kernel is not seeing the audio sound hardware (Realtek ALC1220).

I tried uninstalling dkms and rebooting, then reinstalling dkms.  No change.  How can I find and install the ALC1220 driver?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when Ubuntu queued up the 5.15.0-60 kernel for download, my system didn't also download the linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-60 package.  I downloaded and installed this package and audio functionality was restored.